# An algorithm that determines the minimum leaf depth and the number of leaves in that depth

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, binary-tree

I need to make the algorithm that I indicated in the title, but I have a problem with the fact that I don’t know how to make it write out the number of leafs

**My code:**

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self , key):
        self.data = key
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
 
def minDepth(root):
    if root is None:
        return 0
    if root.left is None and root.right is None:
        return 1
    if root.left is None:
        return minDepth(root.right)+1
    if root.right is None:
        return minDepth(root.left) +1
     
    return min(minDepth(root.left), minDepth(root.right))+1
root = Node(1)
root.left = Node(2)
root.right = Node(3)
root.left.left = Node(4)
root.left.right = Node(5)
print (minDepth(root))
```

So I would like to ask if anyone knows how to find the number of leafs at certain depth

Comment: Use Bfs and Dfs tree searching algorithms. Then use a variable for saving max depth and also another one for saving number of leaves in that depth.

Comment: Could you please clarify what it is that you call a leaf? In particular, consider the tree `Node(key, None, None)`. Is it one root with two leaves, or is it one leaf on its own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After finding the minimum depth using your current DFS algorithm, you can perform another DFS search, except you pass along as parameters the 'desired depth' and 'current depth'.

```py
def count_leaves_at_depth(root, desired_depth, current_depth):
    if root is None or current_depth > desired_depth:
        return 0
    
    if root.left is None and root.right is None:
        return 1 if current_depth == desired_depth else 0
    
    if root.left is None:
        return count_leaves_at_depth(root=root.right,
                                     desired_depth=desired_depth,
                                     current_depth=current_depth + 1)
    
    if root.right is None:
        return count_leaves_at_depth(root=root.left,
                                     desired_depth=desired_depth,
                                     current_depth=current_depth + 1)

    return (count_leaves_at_depth(root=root.right,
                                  desired_depth=desired_depth,
                                  current_depth=current_depth + 1)
            + count_leaves_at_depth(root=root.left,
                                    desired_depth=desired_depth,
                                    current_depth=current_depth + 1))

print(count_leaves_at_depth(root=root,
                            desired_depth=minDepth(root),
                            current_depth=1))
```

Comment: To avoid code duplication, you could do: `count_left = 0 if root.left is None else (recursive call); count_right = 0 if root.right is None else (recursive call); return count_left + count_right`.

Comment: @Stef Good point. In fact the last 2 `if` statements can be removed entirely. Your approach is cleaner, though.